# Getting Summary Data for Longitudinal Data in R

Tags: r, panel-data, longitudinal

I have a set of longitudinal data, which is a number of patients followed up over several years at irregular time points, I am unable to post it due to confidentiality issues,

Essentially, each row represents a single patient encounter, with admission date, discharge date, patient identifier and various demographic (e.g. ethnicity) and other variables,

e.g:

| Patient | Admission Date | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26-01-2007 | White |
| 1 | 28-08-2008 | White |
| 2 | 12-02-2001 | Black |
| 2 | 01-12-2015 | Black |
| 2 | 03-12-2018 | Black |

I've tried using various packages such as brolgar and tsibble, but am unable to get simple summary statistics like number of individual patients, number of encounters per patient, time from first to last attendance per patient in each ethnic category (this one probably deserves another question as it's probably a lot more difficult) for example,

In a standard dataset you could use dplyr to do something like:

```
    df %>%
    group_by(Ethnicity) %>%
    summarise(n=n)
```

to count the number of patients per group,

But I'm not sure how to do it for this dataset despite having gone through packages like brolgar/tsibble,

Would be grateful for any advice

Thanks a lot

Comment: Number of encounters per patient would be: df %>% group_by(Patient) %>% summarize(n=n())

Answer (score 0):

I've done this :

```
df <- data.frame("Patient" = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 3)),
             "Admission Date" = c("26-01-2007", "28-08-2008", "12-02-2001", "01-12-2015", "03-12-2018"),
             "Ethnicity" = c(rep("White", 2), rep("Black", 3)),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

individual_patient <- n_distinct(df$Patient)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Patient) %>% summarise(Encounter_number = n())
```

Are they other things you need to compute ?